# Qual a diferença entre usar forwardRef ou outra prop para passar a referência?

Tags: react

A [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) diz que o encaminhamento de referência é uma técnica para passar a `ref` de um componente pai para um filho, e dá exemplos com `React.forwardRef`.

Mas qual a diferença entre encaminhar referências usando `React.forwardRef` ou simplesmente usando uma prop diferente, como o Material UI faz no componente [`<TextField />`](https://material-ui.com/pt/api/text-field/#component-name) com a prop `inputRef`?

Existem pontos positivos que uma abordagem traz e a outra não?

Comment: Para quem negativou essa pergunta, se quiser cooperar dizendo o que ela tem de ruim para que possa ser melhorado, a comunidade agradece. Se preferir, [é possível melhorar uma pergunta que não é sua](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8601/100416) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diferença é que, quando você utiliza o nome `ref`, está aderindo a uma convenção já estabelecida na comunidade. Portanto, se um componente que você desenvolve irá exigir, de quem o consome, uma referência, utilizar `React.forwardRef` é mais adequado já que poderá utilizar o nome `ref`.

Uma outra diferença é que, ao contrário de `inputRef` (que é, de fato, uma *prop*), `ref` não é passada a componentes como propriedade. Isso é mencionado na [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Não vou explicar como o `React.forwardRef` funciona porque a [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) já é extremamente clara no assunto.

---

Eventualmente, mais de uma referência precisa ser passada ao componente. Nesses casos, você é obrigado a passar as próximas via *props*. É o caso da `inputRef`, mencionada na pergunta.

Da documentação linkada por você:

> `inputRef`, of type `ref`, pass a `ref` to the input element.

E no final ainda diz:

> The `ref` is forwarded to the root element.

De fato, se verificarmos o [código-fonte do componente em questão](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/39379dbc4924b9a5e0dcddf8a7e6925c5a9ce7e3/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L71), pode-se confirmar que ele utiliza o `React.forwardRef` para encaminhar a referência qualificada como `ref`. A propriedade `inputRef`, pois, torna-se necessária já que mais de uma referência pode ser utilizada nesse componente, tal que:

- `ref` é encaminhada ao componente (interno) `TextFieldRoot`;
- `inputRef` é encaminhada ao componente (também interno) `InputComponent`.

Comment: É, cometi uma gafe falando "_outra prop_" hehe.

Answer (score -5):

No React só existe uma forma de passar ref para outro componente, que é com o React.forwardRef.

O que o material-ui faz, é basicamente usar o React.forwardRef no componente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link do código no github oficial](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/39379dbc4924b9a5e0dcddf8a7e6925c5a9ce7e3/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L71)